# Node.js File Output Incomplete

Tags: node.js

I've got a script that I'm toying around with to format all generated permutations for a specific scenario so that I can then create an array of strings for the next part. For whatever reason, when I output to my 'output' file, the file stops at ' ["1-12-17-"], ' when it should end on ' ["25-24-23-"], ' The console output ends on the right string but the text file stops short.

Here's the code:

```
    var fs = require('fs');

    // 13800
    var input = [ [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 5], [1, 2, 6], [1, 2, 7], [1, 2, 8], [1, 2, 9], [1, 2, 10], [1, 2, 11], [1, 2, 12], [1, 2, 13], [1, 2, 14], [1, 2, 15], [1, 2, 16], [1, 2, 17], [1, 2, 18], [1, 2, 19], [1, 2, 20], [1, 2, 21], [1, 2, 22], [1, 2, 23], [1, 2, 24], [1, 2, 25], [1, 3, 2], [1, 3, 4], [1, 3, 5], [1, 3, 6], [1, 3, 7], [1, 3, 8], [1, 3, 9], [1, 3, 10], [1, 3, 11], [1, 3, 12], [1, 3, 13], [1, 3, 14], [1, 3, 15], [1, 3, 16], [1, 3, 17], [1, 3, 18], [1, 3, 19], [1, 3, 20], [1, 3, 21], [1, 3, 22], [1, 3, 23], [1, 3, 24], [1, 3, 25], [1, 4, 2], [1, 4, 3], [1, 4, 5], [1, 4, 6], [1, 4, 7], [1, 4, 8], [1, 4, 9], [1, 4, 10], [1, 4, 11], [1, 4, 12], [1, 4, 13], [1, 4, 14], [1, 4, 15], [1, 4, 16], [1, 4, 17], [1, 4, 18], [1, 4, 19], [1, 4, 20], [1, 4, 21], [1, 4, 22], [1, 4, 23], [1, 4, 24], [1, 4, 25], [1, 5, 2], [1, 5, 3], [1, 5, 4], [1, 5, 6], [1, 5, 7], [1, 5, 8], [1, 5, 9], [1, 5, 10], [1, 5, 11], [1, 5, 12], [1, 5, 13], [1, 5, 14], [1, 5, 15], [1, 5, 16], [1, 5, 17], [1, 5, 18], [1, 5, 19], [1, 5, 20], [1, 5, 21], [1, 5, 22], [1, 5, 23], [1, 5, 24], [1, 5, 25], [1, 6, 2], [1, 6, 3], [1, 6, 4], [1, 6, 5], [1, 6, 7], [1, 6, 8], [1, 6, 9], [1, 6, 10], [1, 6, 11], [1, 6, 12], [1, 6, 13], [1, 6, 14], [1, 6, 15], [1, 6, 16], [1, 6, 17], [1, 6, 18], [1, 6, 19], [1, 6, 20], [1, 6, 21], [1, 6, 22], [1, 6, 23], [1, 6, 24], [1, 6, 25], [1, 7, 2], [1, 7, 3], [1, 7, 4], [1, 7, 5], [1, 7, 6], [1, 7, 8], [1, 7, 9], [1, 7, 10], [1, 7, 11], [1, 7, 12], [1, 7, 13], [1, 7, 14], [1, 7, 15], [1, 7, 16], [1, 7, 17], [1, 7, 18], [1, 7, 19], [1, 7, 20], [1, 7, 21], [1, 7, 22], [1, 7, 23], [1, 7, 24], [1, 7, 25], [1, 8, 2], [1, 8, 3], [1, 8, 4], [1, 8, 5], [1, 8, 6], [1, 8, 7], [1, 8, 9], [1, 8, 10], [1, 8, 11], [1, 8, 12], [1, 8, 13], [1, 8, 14], [1, 8, 15], [1, 8, 16], [1, 8, 17], [1, 8, 18], [1, 8, 19], [1, 8, 20], [1, 8, 21], [1, 8, 22], [1, 8, 23], [1, 8, 24], [1, 8, 25], [1, 9, 2], [1, 9, 3], [1, 9, 4], [1, 9, 5], [1, 9, 6], [1, 9, 7], [1, 9, 8], [1, 9, 10], [1, 9, 11], [1, 9, 12], [1, 9, 13], [1, 9, 14], [1, 9, 15], [1, 9, 16], [1, 9, 17], [1, 9, 18], [1, 9, 19], [1, 9, 20], [1, 9, 21], [1, 9, 22], [1, 9, 23], [1, 9, 24], [1, 9, 25], [1, 10, 2], [1, 10, 3], [1, 10, 4], [1, 10, 5], [1, 10, 6], [1, 10, 7], [1, 10, 8], [1, 10, 9], [1, 10, 11], [1, 10, 12], [1, 10, 13], [1, 10, 14], [1, 10, 15], [1, 10, 16], [1, 10, 17], [1, 10, 18], [1, 10, 19], [1, 10, 20], [1, 10, 21], [1, 10, 22], [1, 10, 23], [1, 10, 24], [1, 10, 25], [1, 11, 2], [1, 11, 3], [1, 11, 4], [1, 11, 5], [1, 11, 6], [1, 11, 7], [1, 11, 8], [1, 11, 9], [1, 11, 10], [1, 11, 12], [1, 11, 13], [1, 11, 14], [1, 11, 15], [1, 11, 16], [1, 11, 17], [1, 11, 18], [1, 11, 19], [1, 11, 20], [1, 11, 21], [1, 11, 22], [1, 11, 23], [1, 11, 24], [1, 11, 25], [1, 12, 2], [1, 12, 3], [1, 12, 4], [1, 12, 5], [1, 12, 6], [1, 12, 7], [1, 12, 8], [1, 12, 9], [1, 12, 10], [1, 12, 11], [1, 12, 13], [1, 12, 14], [1, 12, 15], [1, 12, 16], [1, 12, 17], [1, 12, 18], [1, 12, 19], [1, 12, 20], [1, 12, 21], [1, 12, 22], [1, 12, 23], [1, 12, 24], [1, 12, 25], [1, 13, 2], [1, 13, 3], [1, 13, 4], [1, 13, 5], [1, 13, 6], [1, 13, 7], [1, 13, 8], [1, 13, 9], [1, 13, 10], [1, 13, 11], [1, 13, 12], [1, 13, 14], [1, 13, 15], [1, 13, 16], [1, 13, 17], [1, 13, 18], [1, 13, 19], [1, 13, 20], [1, 13, 21], [1, 13, 22], [1, 13, 23], [1, 13, 24], [1, 13, 25], [1, 14, 2], [1, 14, 3], [1, 14, 4], [1, 14, 5], [1, 14, 6], [1, 14, 7], [1, 14, 8], [1, 14, 9], [1, 14, 10], [1, 14, 11], [1, 14, 12], [1, 14, 13], [1, 14, 15], [1, 14, 16], [1, 14, 17], [1, 14, 18], [1, 14, 19], [1, 14, 20], [1, 14, 21], [1, 14, 22], [1, 14, 23], [1, 14, 24], [1, 14, 25], [1, 15, 2], [1, 15, 3], [1, 15, 4], [1, 15, 5], [1, 15, 6], [1, 15, 7], [1, 15, 8], [1, 15, 9], [1, 15, 10], [1, 15, 11], [1, 15, 12], [1, 15, 13], [1, 15, 14], [1, 15, 16], [1, 15, 17], [1, 15, 18], [1, 15, 19], [1, 15, 20], [1, 15, 21], [1, 15, 22], [1, 15, 23], [1, 15, 24], [1, 15, 25], [1, 16, 2], [1, 16, 3], [1, 16, 4], [1, 16, 5], [1, 16, 6], [1, 16, 7], [1, 16, 8], [1, 16, 9], [1, 16, 10], [1, 16, 11], [1, 16, 12], [1, 16, 13], [1, 16, 14], [1, 16, 15], [1, 16, 17], [1, 16, 18], [1, 16, 19], [1, 16, 20], [1, 16, 21], [1, 16, 22], [1, 16, 23], [1, 16, 24], [1, 16, 25], [1, 17, 2], [1, 17, 3], [1, 17, 4], [1, 17, 5], [1, 17, 6], [1, 17, 7], [1, 17, 8], [1, 17, 9], [1, 17, 10], [1, 17, 11], [1, 17, 12], [1, 17, 13], [1, 17, 14], [1, 17, 15], [1, 17, 16], [1, 17, 18], [1, 17, 19], [1, 17, 20], [1, 17, 21], [1, 17, 22], [1, 17, 23], [1, 17, 24], [1, 17, 25], [1, 18, 2], [1, 18, 3], [1, 18, 4], [1, 18, 5], [1, 18, 6], [1, 18, 7], [1, 18, 8], [1, 18, 9], [1, 18, 10], [1, 18, 11], [1, 18, 12], [1, 18, 13], [1, 18, 14], [1, 18, 15], [1, 18, 16], [1, 18, 17], [1, 18, 19], [1, 18, 20], [1, 18, 21], [1, 18, 22], [1, 18, 23], [1, 18, 24], [1, 18, 25], [1, 19, 2], [1, 19, 3], [1, 19, 4], [1, 19, 5], [1, 19, 6], [1, 19, 7], [1, 19, 8], [1, 19, 9], [1, 19, 10], [1, 19, 11], [1, 19, 12], [1, 19, 13], [1, 19, 14], [1, 19, 15], [1, 19, 16], [1, 19, 17], [1, 19, 18], [1, 19, 20], [1, 19, 21], [1, 19, 22], [1, 19, 23], [1, 19, 24], [1, 19, 25], [1, 20, 2], [1, 20, 3], [1, 20, 4], [1, 20, 5], [1, 20, 6], [1, 20, 7], [1, 20, 8], [1, 20, 9], [1, 20, 10], [1, 20, 11], [1, 20, 12], [1, 20, 13], [1, 20, 14], [1, 20, 15], [1, 20, 16], [1, 20, 17], [1, 20, 18], [1, 20, 19], [1, 20, 21], [1, 20, 22], [1, 20, 23], [1, 20, 24], [1, 20, 25], [1, 21, 2], [1, 21, 3], [1, 21, 4], [1, 21, 5], [1, 21, 6], [1, 21, 7], [1, 21, 8], [1, 21, 9], [1, 21, 10], [1, 21, 11], [1, 21, 12], [1, 21, 13], [1, 21, 14], [1, 21, 15], [1, 21, 16], [1, 21, 17], [1, 21, 18], [1, 21, 19], [1, 21, 20], [1, 21, 22], [1, 21, 23], [1, 21, 24], [1, 21, 25], [1, 22, 2], [1, 22, 3], [1, 22, 4], [1, 22, 5], [1, 22, 6], [1, 22, 7], [1, 22, 8], [1, 22, 9], [1, 22, 10], [1, 22, 11], [1, 22, 12], [1, 22, 13], [1, 22, 14], [1, 22, 15], [1, 22, 16], [1, 22, 17], [1, 22, 18], [1, 22, 19], [1, 22, 20], [1, 22, 21], [1, 22, 23], [1, 22, 24], [1, 22, 25], [1, 23, 2], [1, 23, 3], [1, 23, 4], [1, 23, 5], [1, 23, 6], [1, 23, 7], [1, 23, 8], [1, 23, 9], [1, 23, 10], [1, 23, 11], [1, 23, 12], [1, 23, 13], [1, 23, 14], [1, 23, 15], [1, 23, 16], [1, 23, 17], [1, 23, 18], [1, 23, 19], [1, 23, 20], [1, 23, 21], [1, 23, 22], [1, 23, 24], [1, 23, 25], [1, 24, 2], [1, 24, 3], [1, 24, 4], [1, 24, 5], [1, 24, 6], [1, 24, 7], [1, 24, 8], [1, 24, 9], [1, 24, 10], [1, 24, 11], [1, 24, 12], [1, 24, 13], [1, 24, 14], [1, 24, 15], [1, 24, 16], [1, 24, 17], [1, 24, 18], [1, 24, 19], [1, 24, 20], [1, 24, 21], [1, 24, 22], [1, 24, 23], [1, 24, 25], [1, 25, 2], [1, 25, 3], [1, 25, 4], [1, 25, 5], [1, 25, 6], [1, 25, 7], [1, 25, 8], [1, 25, 9], [1, 25, 10], [1, 25, 11], [1, 25, 12], [1, 25, 13], [1, 25, 14], [1, 25, 15], [1, 25, 16], [1, 25, 17], [1, 25, 18], [1, 25, 19], [1, 25, 20], [1, 25, 21], [1, 25, 22], [1, 25, 23], [1, 25, 24] ]; 

    // I had to dramatically shorten the data

    var temp = [];

    //console.log(input.length);

    for (var x = 0; x < input.length; x++) {
        temp[x] = "[\"" + input[x][0] + "-" + input[x][1] + "-" + input[x][2] + "-\"], ";

        if (true) {
            fs.appendFile("output", temp[x], function (err) {});
            console.log("HERE - " + temp[x]);
        }
    }
```

Any ideas? Could the output indicate a limitation of node.js? Or perhaps it's a file line limitation?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fs.appendFile is asynchronous, so writes to file might not occur in order you would expect. You can easily fix the problem by using fs.appendFileSync instead of fs.appendFile. Or you could change your code to use asynchronous method in the right way:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var input = [];
for (var i = 1; i < 25; i++)
    for (var j = 1; j < 25; j++)
        for (var k = 1; k < 25; k++)
            input.push([i, j, k]);

var temp = [];

/* Synchronous method */
for (var x = 0; x < input.length; x++) {
    temp[x] = makeStr(input[x]);

    fs.appendFileSync("output.txt", temp[x]);
    console.log("HERE - " + temp[x]);
}

/* Asynchronous method */
var i = 0,
    callback = function (err) {
        i++;
        if (!err && i < input.length) {
            temp.push(makeStr(input[i]));
            fs.appendFile("output.txt", temp[i], callback);
        }
    };

temp.push(makeStr(input[i]));
fs.appendFile("output.txt", temp[i], callback);

function makeStr(item) {
    return '["' + item[0] + '-' + item[1] + '-' + item[2] + '"]';
}
```

Comment: I'm impressed by your quick response! I'll have to look into what it means to be Asynchronous or Synchronous on my own, but thank you for fixing my problem.